# chrome.downloads is stuck in "in_progress"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I print out

```
chrome.downloads.search({
    }, function(items) {
        console.log(items[0].state);
    }
});
```

...it says `in_progress`, while there's no obvious download happening. Is there a way to refresh it out somehow so that it doesn't say `in progress`?

How can I see what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I now know what the issue is:

I restarted my Chrome by typing `chrome://restart`. Chrome had new UI this time, apparently it was just updating: the `in_progress` was showing Chrome update!